# inheritance in C#: create an instance initialized with values of a superclass instance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but here goes..

I have a custom class in C# called Person which has a few properties such as Age, Height etc.

I then make a new class called Employee which inherits from Person but I don't yet add any other properties to Employee. So its basically just a Person still, except its called an Employee.

Now say I have an instance of Person called SomePerson. How can I create a new Employee instance that has all of the values it inherited from Person, set to those inside SomePerson. Like casting from a Person into an Employee.. But without me having to manually specify each and every property that needs to be set..

Something like..

```
Employee NewEmployee = (Employee)SomePerson;
```

But of course you get the error saying "Can't convert a Person into an Employee" etc.

Is AutoMapper the only practical solution to do things like this if you say had 300 properties in the involved objects??

**UPDATE:**

Auto-Mapper doesn't seem to handle my objects..

```
Employee SomeEmployee = EmployeeRepository.GetEmployee(SomeEmployeeID);

// Populate the ViewModel with the Person fetched from the db, ready for editing..
VMEmployee EmployeeToEdit = Mapper.Map<Employee, VMEmployee>(SomeEmployee);


// ViewModel based on Employee with Validation applied..
[MetadataType(typeof(Employee_Validation))]
public class VMEmployee : Employee
{
    // Absolutely nothing here
}
```

where "Employee" is auto-generated by LINQ to SQL..

Comment: Soulution you are looking for is called multiple inheritance in C# which doesn't exist.

Comment: I would remove the inheritance of `VMEmployee : Employee`.  You need to define your view model with a subset of properties from your `Employee` domain model.

Comment: Why am I using DataAnnotations again? If I'm manually re-specifying every property 4 times this becomes ridiculous. Once in each of the two ViewModels and once in each of the two validation classes. That is totally ridiculous. Just to have validation on two different situations. I might as well write the validation by hand the old school way. There has to be a smarter way.. Otherwise DataAnnotations is useless.

Comment: You don't need to use separate buddy classes with your view model.  Just apply your DataAnnotations to your view model itself.  Buddy classes are intended for when you are using your domain objects directly in your view and you don't have control over the properties generated for you, hence implementing a buddy class to handle the validation.  Your view model is a separate class completely with its own properties. Redefine your view model.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Matthew. That has taught me something valuable and now seems obvious! That reduces duplication nicely, but one further question/issue.. This still leaves me with needing AutoMapper to set the ViewModel values after retrieving the object from the database before editing??

Comment: Matthew please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636707/asp-net-mvc2-set-viewmodel-values-with-retrieved-from-db-objects-values-with-d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoMapper is a good solution in this case.  If you're not going to use a property mapping framework, and you're not willing to create a copy constructor `public Employee(Person person)`, or an implicit/explicit conversion, how else do you expect to copy the properties across.  Realistically you could

1.Reflection

```
public void Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
{
  var props = typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  var type = typeof(TDestination);

  foreach (var prop in props)
  {
    object value = prop.GetValue(source, null);

    var prop2 = type.GetProperty(prop.Name);
    if (prop2 == null)
      continue;

    if (prop.PropertyType != prop2.PropertyType)
      continue;

    prop2.SetValue(destination, value, null);
  }
}
```

2.Copy Constructor

```
public Employee(Person person)
{
  // Copy properties
}
```

3.Implicit/Explicit Conversion

```
public static implicit operator Employee(Person person)
{
  // Build instance and return
}
```

4.AutoMapper

```
Mapper.Map<Person, Employee>(person);
```

5.Combination of 3/4:

```
public static implicit operator Employee(Person person)
{
  return Mapper.Map<Person, Employee>(person);
}
```

A note on implicit/explicit conversion operators: I believe in using these you won't be generating CLS-compliant code.

As @Mitch Wheat has already said, if you have an object with over 300 properties, I would reconsider what that object actually represents. Refactor refactor refactor.

Comment: Ok AutoMapper it is. Does it work with child complex objects?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, AutoMapper supports projection, so when you are wiring up your map, `Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Employee>().ForMember(e => e.ComplexProperty, o => o.MapFrom(p => new ComplexProperty(p.Name)));`  You should have a look at the examples (http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Trying to map MyProject.Data.Employee to MyProject.ViewModels.VMEmployee.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

Comment: Thanks I will check the examples. But it looks like I will manually have to specify each complex property that needs mapping?

Comment: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping". Is this because my complex object is auto-generated by LINQ to SQL!??!?!?!?!??!

Comment: OK buzz off AutoMapper. This is exactly what I mean about add-ons. It can't even do LINQ to SQL generated classes properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [automaper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this purpose, without any configuration.

here's an example:

```
Employee employee = Mapper.Map<Person, Employee>(person);
```

Comment: So far I am liking this the most as it (a) doesn't involve hardcore hacks such as Reflection, (b) involves a single line of code and (c) involves no configuration.. My next question is why isn't something like this built into .Net in some way. The need is growing particularly with ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: How many DLLs do you have to add to your Bin folder to use AutoMapper? I'm no fan of unnecessary bloat.

Comment: Exactly my own school of thought. As a general rule, the more add-ons, the less reliability and higher the future maintenance. I am very anti add-ons in general. You come back in 3 years time when ASP.Net MVC10 is out and suddenly your solution doesn't build because you're running AutoMapper 1.01. That is the problem with add-ons and I have learnt this from experience with working on some mammoth solutions with way too many add-ons. Anyway, I'm desperate and investigating AutoMapper. The author seems smart, its just a single DLL and very low bloat.

Comment: This exact code doesn't work :(

Trying to map MyProject.Data.Employee to MyProject.ViewModels.VMEmployee. Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor on `Employee` that takes a `Person` instance. Of course you'll have to fill in all the properties (maybe Resharper can help?)

Comment: Yeah ok, but I want to avoid manually setting the values of each and every property one by one as I have hundreds of them.

Comment: @Aaron: 1. Reflection (ugh!), 2. ReSharper (maybe), 3. A class with 300 properties?  Drawing Board....

Comment: Ok there aren't 300 of them, but they are complex LINQ to SQL Model classes. And they contain child complex classes as well. E.g. Address (which in itself might have StreetName, StreetNumber and so on etc..)

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I think I know the answer already.

IMPOSSIBLE.

In that case, ASP.Net MVC's Model Validation needs some much needed further improvements.

Comment: @Aaron: are you placing your custom validation attributes on Person's properties?

Comment: I'm putting them on Employee deliberately, because I need to validate the creation of Persons in two different situations differently. Two sites: WWW site and internal admin site. On WWW some fields are mandatory which are NOT mandatory when the same object is being created through the internal admin site. Therefore I need two different validation "rule sets" if you like. I am using DataAnnotations and laying the MetadataType tag over the top of the class I need to validate. This is what lead me to needing two classes which inherit from Person. Its really Person_www and Person_Admin..

Comment: So what you're describing is basically role-based validation rule sets? If that's the case, then you could keep one Person class and instead manage your validation through a separate role provider of sorts. The role provider would then determine the Person object's Role property value and handle logic accordingly. At least that's how I would refactor, but that's for a different discussion.

Comment: But that doesn't sound like it uses DataAnnotations. Have you used them much? I am loving them, they have saved a lot of time. It would be nice to just stick with them and keep it all clean rather than building custom crap all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relatively simple properties, reflection will probably be the quickest and easiest solution to map property values.

Contrary to popular belief, reflection really isn't that bad; Rick Strahl dispels this myth in this article: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/351.aspx.

Create the following constructor for `Employee`:

```
public Employee(Person person)
{
    // clone property values
    foreach (var property in person.GetType().GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite))
    {
        property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(user, null), null);
    }
}
```

Now simply instantiate an `Employee` object like so:

```
Employee NewEmployee = new Employee(SomePerson);
```

Comment: Thanks brilly. I like your thinking of sticking with native MS issue code that has a better future life likelihood, but in my case, I am dealing with complex objects with child complex objects, all auto-generated by LINQ to SQL. So I think this is where AutoMapper has a reputation for shining more..

Answer (score 0):

"they are complex LINQ to SQL Model classes" -- Aaron

If you have a table that maps to one of several possible classes, you can use [LINQ to SQL's Inheritance Hierarchies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352.aspx). It means that if you use the same table for several types of conceptual entities, you can have LINQ to SQL automatically create the appropriate class. Each class can have different properties which can be a subset of the columns in the table.

There are some limitations. You can use only one table per inheritance hierarchy and you must have a discriminator column that tells LINQ to SQL which class should be used.

Answer (score -2):

When you start a new job, is a new person born who is not you, and the old you killed?

If your design is based on that scenario, as it appears, then the practice in your organisation is very strange.

Instead, a person has an employment relationship with an employer.

Don't use inheritance to model roles; allow the same person to have roles which represent their relationships with other objects.

Comment: Yeah totally agree, but I am just making up the Person/Employee example to make a very peculiar situation easy to communicate..

Comment: @Aaron Then use an example which actually matches the problem, otherwise it's not a real question

Comment: Ok Pete, here's the full question. See what you can do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636707/asp-net-mvc2-set-viewmodel-values-with-retrieved-from-db-objects-values-with-d